# Use of :upper: in bash script for checking if filename contains an uppercase character

Tags: regex, bash

I came across this piece of bash script for converting filenames which contain an uppercase character into a lowercase name.

```
LIST="$(ls)"

for name in "$LIST"; do

if [[ "$name" != *[[:upper:]]* ]]; then
continue
fi
#... remainder omitted
```

It's the `\*[[:upper:]]\*` character class which I am not sure about. Does it read as *zero or more characters followed by an upper case letter followed by zero or more characters*?

Comment: BTW, `for name in "$LIST"` is innately wrong. It only runs the contents of the loop once, with the entire output of `ls` assigned to the variable `name`.

Comment: Use `for name in *; do` to iterate over names in the current directory.

Comment: As is `LIST=$(ls)` (the quotes making no difference here).

Comment: ...and see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: (Also, as an aside -- technically, this is a glob-style pattern, not a regex; a regex for the same thing would be just `[[:upper:]]`, since they're unanchored by default, or `.*[[:upper:]].*` if you want to make matching surrounding content explicit).

Comment: U could check for  `[ "$name" = "${name,,}" ]` this will have same effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**.

`*[[:upper:]]*` does read as "zero or more characters followed by an upper-case letter followed by zero or more characters". Note that exactly what is considered an upper-case letter depends on the value of `LC_CTYPE` and `LC_ALL` locale-specific variables.

---

That said, if you want to find and rename files with at least one upper-case letter in their names:

```
for file in *[[:upper:]]*; do
  [[ -e $file || -L $file ]] || continue # handle case where glob failed to match
  printf 'Found file with at least one upper-case character: %q\n' "$file"
  mv -- "$file" "${file,,}" ## move file to its all-lowercase-named equivalent
done
```

Note that `${foo,,}` to generate an all-lowercase form of a variable's contents is a fairly new feature, added in bash 4.x.

---

See:

- [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls(1)`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- The Wooledge page on [globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)
- The bash-hackers page on [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) -- this covers `${foo,,}`.
- [BashFAQ #30](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030): "How can I rename all my *.foo files to *.bar, or convert spaces to underscores, or convert upper-case file names to lower case?"

Comment: @njk2015  Please note that this (very good) solution does not handle filename collisions : you may already have a file with the target name of the `mv` command, and many mixed case file names could map to the same lowercase name.  If this bothers you, you could handle failure of the `mv` command explicitly.

Comment: Yup. The examples given in BashFAQ #30 will handle collisions gracefully; someone who needs a fully robust answer is probably better off looking behind that link.

Comment: Thank you for all the links

Comment: Beautiful answer, as always.  No need for `[[ -e $file || -L $file ]] || continue` if we had `shopt -s nullglob` earlier, right?